# How to programmatically adjust z order of Views

Tags: android, view, android-framelayout

The below code is my attempt to send mMyView to the front or the back of the set of children of mPivotParent so it will be rendered on top or behind the others. Hiding the view will *not* suffice in my case.

mPivotParent is a FrameLayout.

Looking at `mPivotParent.mChildren` shows that my code below "works" in that the ordering is being set correctly. Yet it has no impact on the z order. Not only this, but the framerate gets cumulatively slower and slower the more times the repositioning code gets called. There are 4 children total and `mPivotParent.mChildrenCount` remains at 4 throughout as expected.

I'm targeting API Level 7.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    float x = event.getRawX();
    float sWidth = (int)display.getWidth();
    float xLerpFromCenter = ((x / sWidth) - .5f) * 2.f;             // [-1, 1]
    mRotateAnimation.mfLerp = xLerpFromCenter;

    if(xLerpFromCenter < -0.2f && mPivotParent.getChildAt(0) != mMyView)
    {
        mPivotParent.removeView(mMyView);
        mPivotParent.addView(mMyView, 0);
        refreshEverything();
    }
    else if(xLerpFromCenter > 0.2f && mPivotParent.getChildAt(0) == mMyView)
    {
        mPivotParent.removeView(mMyView);
        mPivotParent.addView(mMyView, mPivotParent.getChildCount() - 1);
        refreshEverything();
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private void refreshEverything()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < mPivotParent.getChildCount(); ++i)
    {
        mPivotParent.getChildAt(i).invalidate();
        mPivotParent.getChildAt(i).requestLayout();
    }
    mPivotParent.invalidate();
    mPivotParent.requestLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Partial Solution***

Here's a somewhat inefficient hack but it works for my purpose, which is to take the top item and send it to the back, keeping all other items in their same order.

```
private void putFrontAtBack()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < mPivotParent.getChildCount() - 1; ++i)
    {
        mPivotParent.getChildAt(0).bringToFront();
    }
    refreshEverything();
}
```

***Note:*** This doesn't work in the general case of arbitrary re-ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
private void reorder(int[] order)
{
    if(order == null || order.length != mPivotParent.getChildCount()) return;
    for(int i = order.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        mPivotParent.getChildAt(order[i]).bringToFront();
    }
    refreshEverything();
}
```

This code provides arbitrary reordering. The integer array "order" is used to indicate the new order of each view, where order[n]=x means the new order of childAt(x) is n.